# Why do I get the error of "expr: syntax error" in a simple shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

My script is

```
#! /bin/bash
  
v1="hello"
v2="world1"
subIndex=`expr index "${v1}" "${v2}"`
echo $subIndex
```

and I got the error of "expr: syntax error"

Comment: Could you post _full_ error message verbatim? It's it `expr: syntax error: something something`? And check for dos line endings.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, the BSD expr(1) on, e.g., MacOS 10.15.7 does not have `: something something`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Correct, I am using 10.15.7.

Comment: Note that `expr` in general is best avoided in favor of using bash builtins -- as an external command it's expensive to run (requires forking off a subprocess), and its most-used functionality, arithmetic, is mooted by POSIX.2's inclusion of standard-defined arithmetic operators. One can get `expr index` with clever use of `BASH_REMATCH`, f/e.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a version of `expr` which doesn't have an `index` operator.

As you can see in the POSIX standard [man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html) there's no `index` in the table of operators. The only mention of `index` in that document says that the behaviour is undefined. We can assume that the standardisation process saw that only some implementations supported `index` and some or all of the participants did not want to add the additional functionality.

Some other implementations contain additional functionality above and beyond what is specified in the standard. You'll need to install one of these implementations or change your code. [GNU expr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html) is one implementation that does have `index`, `length`, etc..